# Deserialization failure error in Infragistics webdatagrid V15.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

A large amount of data is loaded in **Webdatagrid** from DB. I am using **virtualscrolling property** of **webdatagrid** to load data dynamically on scrolling. Since there is a number of records, if the scroll is clicked and dragged, then there is a loading symbol which leads to "**Deserialization failure**" error.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to increase the default timeout (20 seconds) of the control callback manager. You could use the protected **_callbackManager** object which is referenced by each Aikido control. To increase the **WebDataGrid** timeout period you can do the following:

***Code snippet:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Init(sender, eventArgs) {
            sender._callbackManager.setTimeout(60000);
        }
 </script>


 ...
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EmployeesDataSource" 
    Width="100%" DataKeyFields="OrderID">
    <ClientEvents Initialize="Init" />
```

Client event **AJAXResponse** also could be used, insted of **Initialize**, it depends of the use case.

Another cause of this failure could be the rendering of the **WebDataGrid** after postback (if any). For example if you have nested **WebDataGrid**, and makes a postback, make sure it is visible and the parent controls is visible also, or the rendering methods wont be called.

In conclusion, make sure that you are following the recommendations from Infragistics [documentation for Virtual Scrolling](http://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/webdatagrid-virtual-scrolling), like configuring **Row Cache Factor**, **Threshold Factor** and **Data Fetch Delay**.